# I don't know what context need's my beacon aplication

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID = "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D";
    private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS = new Region("regionId",
        ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID, null, null);
    public String TAG = "Beacons";

    private BeaconManager beaconManager = new BeaconManager(context);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ranged beacons: " + beacons);
        }
    });
}

...
```

And the problem is in the line 23:

```
private BeaconManager beaconManager = new BeaconManager(context);
```

What i soposed to put instead of "context"?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use - `getApplicationContext()` or you could pass `this`

Comment: new BeaconManager(this) - execute this inside onCreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) is an interface that provides global information about an application environment.
Every activity extends Context. Thats why you can write `this` instead of context.

```
private BeaconManager beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this)
```

Answer (score 1):

More efficient method is declaring global `Context` and initialising it inside `onCreate()` method. It enable you to use the same context for other methods too such as showing Toast.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID = "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D";
private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS = new Region("regionId",
  ESTIMOTE_PROXIMITY_UUID, null, null);
public String TAG = "Beacons";
private Context  context;
private BeaconManager beaconManager;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
context = getApplicationContext();
beaconManager = new BeaconManager(context);
beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Ranged beacons: " + beacons);
    } 
});
```

}

Comment: `this` is not necessary while calling `getApplicationContext()`. You could directly call `getApplicationContext()`